# Rails assets:precompile en ejecución

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo un web con Rails 5, dónde el usuario puede configurar la imagen de fondo, se guarda en una tabla de preferencias,

** Establezco la imagen de fondo con js, porque uso transiciones entre fondos (puede haber mas de una imagen de fondo) y para evitar el barrido cuando carga la siguiente imagen.

El problema está cuando el usuario cambia esta configuración, ya que es entonces cuando necessitaria hacer un `RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile` para que los cambios en `applicacion.js.erb` tengan efecto, en  dicho js tengo algo así:

`Body.css("background-image",url('<%= Preference.first.bg_image url%>')`

¿Se puede hacer un `rails assets:precompile` dentro del mismo programa? (en un controlador por ejemplo)

Creo que me o me dejo algo muy gordo, o estoy diciendo una animalada?

Una opcion que se me ha ocurrido, es usar js a la antigua, sin "assets"

Answer (score 0):

En general dejar de usar los assets te va a traer más  problemas que beneficios, así que creo deja esa parte tal cual está.
Una solución para tu problema podría ser que dentro de un template de las vistas, crear un bloque `<script>` y asignar a una variable global javascript el valor de la url. Otra solución que hace algo muy similar a lo que te describo, pero de manera más limpia es que uses la gema [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) y asignes la url de la imagen a la variable gon a nivel de controlador para luego accederla en tu js. Cualquiera de las 2 opciones te permitirá dejar de precompilar tu javascript con erb.

Comment: He hecho esto que pongo en mi respuesta, no se si es una "chapuza"

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se me ha ocurrido, seguramente lo mas sencillo:

en el body me guardo las imagenes en attributos "tag"

```
<body
    <%preference=Preference.first%>
    <% (1..5).each do |i| %>
      <% if eval("preference.background_#{i}.exists?") %>
        <%= "data-bgi-#{i}="+eval("Preference.first.background_#{i}").url(:original) %>
      <%end%>
    <%end%>
>
```

lo cual genera:

```
<body data-bgi-1= "/fitxers/imatges/configuracio/background/background_1_original.jpg?1470936472" data-bgi-2= "/fitxers/imatges/configuracio/background/background_2_original.jpg?1472313681" data-bgi-3= "/fitxers/imatges/configuracio/background/background_3_original.jpg?1471043414" data-bgi-4= "/fitxers/imatges/configuracio/background/background_4_original.jpg?1472317355" data-bgi-5= "/fitxers/imatges/configuracio/background/background_5_original.jpg?1472318462" style="background-image: url(&quot;/fitxers/imatges/configuracio/background/background_4_original.jpg?1472317355&quot;);">
```

Y en js , consulto estas propiedades cada vez que tengo que mostrar imágenes

Comment: No se ve como la solución más limpia, sobretodo eso de modificar el body, pero mientras te funcione, supongo que está bien